# Failing to Understand Doc2Vec Output

Tags: python, doc2vec

So I started down the path of attempting to learn Doc2Vec, specifically the cosine similarity output. Basically, I am getting an unexpected output when attempting to match a new sentence to the list of sentences I trained my model on. If anyone could help, that would be amazing, here's my code:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

data = [
        'I love machine learning'
        ,'I love coding in python'
        ,'I love building chatbots'
        ,'they chat amazingly well'
        ,'dog poops in my yard'
        ,'this is a stupid exercise'
        ,'I like math and statistics'
        ,'cox communications is a dumb face'
        ,'Machine learning in python is difficult'
        ]

tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words = word_tokenize(d.lower()), tags = [str(i)]) for i, d in enumerate(data)]

max_epochs = 15
vec_size = 10
wndw = 2
alpha_num = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size = vec_size
                ,window = wndw
                ,alpha = alpha_num
                ,min_alpha = 0.00025
                ,min_count = 1
                ,dm = 1)
  
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

model = Doc2Vec(tagged_data, vector_size = 20, window = 2, min_count = 1, workers = 4, epochs = 100)

new_sent = 'machine learning in python is easy'.split(' ')

model.docvecs.most_similar(positive = [model.infer_vector(new_sent)])
```

The output I receive is this (and it's also random each time I run, so I'm not sure about that either):

```
[('2', 0.4818369746208191),
 ('5', 0.4623863697052002),
 ('3', 0.4057881236076355),
 ('4', 0.3984462022781372),
 ('8', 0.2882154583930969),
 ('7', 0.27972114086151123),
 ('6', 0.23783418536186218),
 ('0', 0.11647315323352814),
 ('1', -0.12095103412866592)]
```

Meaning the model is stating that 'I love coding in python' is the most similar to 'machine learning in python is easy', when I would expect 'Machine learning in python is difficult' to be the most similar. At least that's how I'm interpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding the output. The numbers are the indices of the training vectors. Therefore, it is most similar to the vector at index `2`, i.e. `I love building chatbots` and least similar to vector at index `1` i.e. `I love coding in python`.

That being said, don't create two models, one for creating the vectors and one for testing. Only the model you create the vectors with understands the vectors, the other one doesn't.

The wacky results are probably because there isn't enough data for the machine to understand or develop a useful word embedding. Randomness could be because every time you run it a different RNG is rolled when creating word vectors. Try setting the random state if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Doc2Vec` & similar algorithms don't work meaningfully on toy-sized datasets like this. The barest minimum to demo will be something with hundreds of texts, & tens-of-thousands of training words - and for such a (still very small) dataset, you'd again want to reduce the default `vector_size` to something small like your 10-20 values, rather than the default `100`.

So first & foremost, test on a larger dataset. The original paper, and most other non-trivial demos, will use sets of texts in the tens-of-thousands, each at least a dozen and ideally many dozens or hundreds of words long.

Second, your current code is creating an initial `Doc2Vec` instance, then calling `.build_vocab()` on it, then... throwing that model away, and creating an all-new model in your second assignment into the `model` variable. You only need to create one, and it should have just the parameters you really want - not the mix of different parameters in your current code.

Turning on logging at the INFO level will provide output that will help you understand what steps are occurring - and as you learn to read the output, you may see confirmations of good progress, or indicators of problems.

Finally, `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea - these algorithms need multiple examples of a word's use for it not to be noise in the training, and it's usually better to discard singleton (& very-rare) words to allow the others to become better. (Once you're using a larger dataset, losing words than only appear 1 to a few times shouldn't be a big concern.)